# how does alert print array , although it takes strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner in javascript , I have a question , I have an array like

```
       var nameOfName=["john","mark"];
      alert(nameOfName); // or 
document.getElementById("anyelementid").innerHTML=nameOfName; //should also trigger error because we are trying to put array in place of string.
```

why alert or innerhtml shows the results correctly although it's an array, not a string ?
I think in other programming techniques an error should be triggered and a message told us that this is an array to string not allowed conversion .

Comment: i don't search for how to convert or get type , iam asking about why alert accepted array and converted it to string then printed that , and also the same innerHtml  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `alert` with an object value (arrays are objects, just a special case), it automatically calls [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on that value.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
// Notice that they show the same result
alert(arr);
alert(arr.toString());
```

The thing about Javascript is that it's dynamically typed with type coercion. In laymans terms, that means it will automatically try to convert your data to the correct type given the context. For example:

```js
// Converts the number to a string
console.log(1 + '2');

// Converts the booleans values to numbers
console.log(true + true);
```

Comment: and also innerHTML . TRUE ?

Comment: @mina See my edit. Basically, JS will try to convert the data to the correct type for you. `innerHTML` expects a string so it tries to give it a string.

Comment: @mina So? The same idea applies. You're trying to assign an array to something that expects a string. So JS converts the array in to a string and uses that value instead.

Comment: i know that in all programming languages variables comparisons, type casting will be happened, but i need to set a rule for myself , when js will cast for me the variables (like alert and .innerHTML) and when it will trigger conversion error . ?

Comment: @mina It will *never* trigger a conversion error. That's what I'm saying. Some APIs will give you errors if you try to use the wrong type somewhere but the language itself will never, ever, give you a type conversion error.

Comment: so there's no type conversion error in js or there are in special cases ?

Comment: thank you sir for your time . i will continue reading and will take the results as a rules .

Comment: if i made an object and tried to put it in alert it will print it object object but it not converted ??

Comment: @mina Have you tried calling `toString()` on an object? That's what it returns, no matter what is in the object. `var obj = { a: 1 }; alert(obj); alert(obj.toString());`

Comment: that means, js will convert via to string function . that's good , but if you have an article for me in this point , this will a good thing , although iam reading now about automatic js conversion

Comment: @mina [This one is pretty good.](http://www.2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think Alert in javascript parse your array to string to show it, that's why. If you want to know what type of object is, use `typeof`.

If you have a JSON, and want to print it as string, use `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

As javascripts accepts string arrays to display with default `.toString()` methos it wont throws error. if you want to handle catch errors please use try catch like this

```js
var nameOfName=["john","mark"];
try{
document.getElementById("anyelementid").innerHTML=nameOfName;
  }
catch(ex){
document.getElementById("anyelementid").innerHTML=ex.message;
  }
```

```html
<div id="anyelementid"></div>
```